# python code of underwater fusion techniques

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-enhancement

I  am  writing  python code for  underwater image fusion enhancement algorithm(2012 paper and 2018 paper). i am not understanding  logic of weight maps and  pyramids present in the paper . so   if anyone know  please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two implementations I found: 
1. https://github.com/IsaacChanghau/ImageEnhanceViaFusion
2. https://github.com/ajit2704/underwater-image-enhancement